# Maximum Pairwise GCD of an even subsequence

Tags: algorithms

I am trying to solve a particular problem, where I have been given an array of integers and an integer X and I need to choose a subsequence of the array whose pairwise gcd is maximum given that the size of the subsequence must not exceed 2*X.

So for example, my array is [5, 7, 10, 8, 3, 4] and X is 2:
the answer would be 9 since GCD(5, 10) + GCD(8, 4) = 9

The only approach I've been able to come up with was: At each step I'll find the maximum pairwise GCD of the numbers and then remove the 2 numbers from the array.
Will keep adding it to a sum(which I have to output), under the constraints that I dont take in more than 2*X numbers.

Comment: Please edit the question to add a reference to that "particular problem".

Comment: It looks like that particular problem is part of live contest. If you created or discovered the problem on yourself, please introduce the background a bit.

Comment: What does the `even` in the title refer to?

Comment: Something that irritates me: reading *pairwise GCD*, I picture *all pairs*. Tracing the example, I see *pairs* and fail to see *subsequence*.

Comment: A simple example for which OP's algorithm fails could be $[40, 56, 5,7]$ and $X=2$. $g(40,56)+g(5,7)=8+1=9<g(40,5)+g(56,7)=12$